# ffmpeg concatenate images in one image

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I use this to get frames from video and concatenate them in one image:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf 'fps=2,tile=1000x1' out.jpg
```

But there is a problem: I do not know number of frames that will be fetched. Here I hardcoded tile size 1000x1, but if there will be more than 1000 frames, then will be an error. Before starting ffmpeg I do not know actual size of tile.

So I want use command like:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf 'fps=2,tile=*x1' out.jpg
```

That means: I want you to concatenate ALL images that will be fetched in one row, but I cannot use * as an argument for tile.

Is there some way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I got an idea:

```
$ FRAMES=`ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 xxx.mp4`
$ FFMPEG="ffmpeg -i xxx.mp4 -vf 'fps=2,tile=\$FRAMESx1' out.jpg"
$ `echo "${FFMPEG//\$FRAMES/$FRAMES}"`
```